# Self Organizing Network Plot Subset of Codes

Tags: r, som

I have used the Kohonen package in R to apply SOM to a genomics dataset I have. The SOM has 55 variables. I want to plot a subset of the codes for these variables as fanplots. For example, just using the wine dataset innate in R:

```
library(kohonen)
data(wines)
set.seed(7)

training <- sample(nrow(wines), 120)
Xtraining <- scale(wines[training, ])
Xtest <- scale(wines[-training, ],
           center = attr(Xtraining, "scaled:center"),
           scale = attr(Xtraining, "scaled:scale"))

som.wines <- som(Xtraining, grid = somgrid(5, 5, "hexagonal"))
plot(som.wines, type="codes")
```

This plots the weight of every predictor on each node as a fanplot. What I would like to do in this instance is plot say, just magnesium, ash, malic acid and flavonoids in the fanplot.

```
plot(som.wines, type = "property", property = som.wines$codes[,'magnesium'])
```

Will plot the weight for magnesium on each node.

Doing something like

```
plot(som.wines, type = "property", property =som.wines$codes[,c('magnesium','ash')])
```

Just overrides the magnesium weights with ash weights for each node.

Additionally something like:

```
plot(som.wines, type = "codes", property = som.wines$codes[,c('magnesium','ash')],)
```

Does not work either.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: You should provide some form of [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data that we can run so we can see what you are seeing. Describe how you want to choose the subset of predictors. Right now i'm really not sure what kind of answer you are looking for.

Comment: Hi MrFlick, thanks for the advice - I have updated my question which should be more explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

Well, we know

```
class(som.wines)
# [1] "kohonen"
```

So the plotting method that's triggered here is `kohonen:::plot.kohonen`. When you set type="codes", that farms out the command to `kohonen:::plot.kohcodes`. Upon inspection, it only appears to use the `$codes` and `$grid` property of the object you pass it. It appears to be safe if you want to subset those values directly. For example

```
keep <- c("magnesium", "ash", "malic acid", "flavonoids")
xx <- som.wines
xx$codes<-xx$codes[,keep]
plot(xx, type="codes")
```

This produces

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks a million.